# How do I create a function using loops to return the number of upper case and lower case letters on python?

Tags: python, function, loops

- should use str.islower(), str.isupper(), str.istitle()

Comment: Please repeat [on topic]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework]( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

this is a rough code just to explain better.
you can do that as you said:

```
def analyze(string): # define the function named analyze
    upper = 0
    lower = 0
    for i in string:
        if i.isupper():
            upper += 1
        if i.islower():
            lower += 1
     inupper = string.title()
     return lower, upper, inupper
analyze(input("something to input")) 
# if you want it in the function just put the input in the function.
print(analyze(input("something to input")))
```

in the question, it sounds like you wanted it on title case, though, you wanted to use "istitle()" that just indicates if it is a title case. this is my first answer so hopefully, it fits in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented an example for you. I have added many comment to my code for the better understanding.

**Code:**

```
def converter(input_text):
    """
    Returns the number of upper case letters, lower case letters, as well as
    converting the string to Title Case.
    :param input_text: Text from the user.
    :return: number of upper case letters, lower case letters, Title Case string.
    """

    upper_case_counter = lower_case_counter = 0  # Define the counters

    for letter in input_text:  # Get the letters one-by-one
        if letter.isupper():  # True if the letter is upper case
            upper_case_counter += 1  # Increment the upper counter
            continue  # Get the next letter
        lower_case_counter += 1  # Increment the lower case counter (If the "if" statement is not True)

    return upper_case_counter, lower_case_counter, input_text.title()  # Return the upper, lower, title (In tuple type)


user_input = input("Please write your text: ")  # Get the input from user
upper, lower, title = converter(user_input)  # Unpacking the return value of "converter" function
print("Upper case letters number:{}\n"
      "Lower case letters number: {}\n"
      "Title text: {}".format(upper, lower, title))  # Print the result
```

If you have to use the `x.islower()` then your can do it like this:

```
for letter in input_text:  # Get the letters one-by-one
    if letter.isupper():  # True if the letter is upper case
        upper_case_counter += 1  # Increment the upper counter
    elif letter.islower():  # True if the letter is lower case
        lower_case_counter += 1  # Increment the lower case counter
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py  
Please write your text: This is my TExt
Upper case letters number:3
Lower case letters number: 12
Title text: This Is My Text
```